# Software Center crashing

Tags: software-center

Any time I try to run the Ubuntu software center it immediately crashes. I go to terminal and type in 'software-center' and this is the results I get. Any help.

```
2014-04-22 09:29:28,526 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2014-04-22 09:29:28,987 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-04-22 09:29:28,990 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2014-04-22 09:29:28,994 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2014-04-22 09:29:28,994 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2014-04-22 09:29:29,035 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2014-04-22 09:29:29,604 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2014-04-22 09:29:29,605 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 155, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
2014-04-22 09:29:30,054 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1375, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1313, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Comment: Can you try `rm ~/.cache/software-center` and retry opening the software center?

Comment: I tried this but it told me i wasn't able to remove this as it was a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-installing Software-center:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

And  its a **Bad** idea but see if software-center is able to run as root

```
gksudo software-center
```

PS: Running software-center as root is highly not recommended, check [this Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401772/running-software-center-from-command-line-as-root) for more info.

If you dont have gksudo installed then install it using

```
sudo apt-get install gksudo
```

Comment: I tried rm~/.cache/software-center and was told that it cannot be removed. is a directory.

Also Tried What you suggested Back.Slash and it did not work... when I tried the 'sudo apt-get install software-installer' i got unable to locate package software-installer

Comment: my bad its `software-center` not `software-installer` (edited the answer). Also for removing try `rm -r ~/.cache/software-center`

Comment: I am still unable to run it... i removed the cache from software-center first but that didn't help... so i removed software center then tried to reinstall with the sudo apt-get install software-center and it still isn't running i get this return:

Comment: SystemError: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I get this error among other errors, but i think this is the main error

Comment: Looks like you have a malformed entry on line 57 in  `/etc/apt/sources.list`. do `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and post content of line 57, Also check http://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update

Comment: Also can you try `sudo ls` and reply is its working without any error?

Comment: just type in 'sudo ls'? I did that and it brought up a few directories like i typed in 'dir'

Comment: therefore `sudo` is working fine

Comment: check whats written on line 57 `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 249AD24C

Comment: it is saying that installed packages have unmet dependencies in my toolbar

Comment: comment line 57 by adding `#` in front of the line, and do a `sudo apt-get update` and then try running `software-center` from terminal

Comment: any way of figuring that out?

Comment: still closing on me

Comment: same error? did you save the `/etc/apt/sources.list` you need to edit as root using `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to save changes

Comment: Ok I got it fixed. Thanks for all your help!

I fixed the file by commenting on that line then saved it. (Which I did earlier, but I was missing a space between the # and the sudo). I then 'sudo apt-get purge software-center' to remove software-center. After, I reinstalled software center by running 'sudo apt-get install software-center'. Finally I ran 'sudo apt-get update'. Then opened software center.

Seems to be working well now!

Comment: no problem, just mark the question as answered :)

Comment: how? Sorry I am new and don't know